# Guardar imagen en Base de Datos de modo que pueda subirlo a Github y otra persona pueda abrirlo sin problemas

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, jsp, servlets

tengo la siguiente duda:

Estoy haciendo una página web en Java (con jsp y servlet) con un compañero, y quiero guardar una imagen en la BD. Sé que se hace guardando la URL pero me guarda lo suguiente: C:\Users\miUsuario\eclipse-workspace\Proyecto\images\nombreImagen.jpg

Al compartirlo en github obviamente mi compañero no podrá verlo.

¿Qué puedo hacer al respecto? Busqué en varios idiomas y no encuentro respuesta...

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si guardas la URL guardas la URL, no la imagen (la imagen en la URL puede cambiar, desaparecer, el servidor dejar de dar servicio). Para realmente guardar la imagen, busca "mysql BLOB". Aunque sigo sin saber qué tiene que ver github con esto...

Comment: Que necesito compartir el proyecto. Con la url  C:\Users\miUsuario\eclipse-workspace\Proyecto\images\nombreImagen.jpg  mi compañero no podrá ver las imagenes en el JSP, con la etiqueta <a>

Comment: necesitas guardar la imagen en tu proyecto par asi al subirla la puede compartir

Comment: Si si, está en mi proyecto.

Comment: Lo que necesitas hacer es hacer referencia a tu imagen no como una ruta de archivo local, sino como un recurso dentro de la webapp (`ServletContext.getContextPath` o `ServletContext.getRealPath` o `ServletContext.getResource` o...) Como no pones código es difícil saber cómo usas la imagen y dar una respuesta, ([ask]).